# Remove distortion from plastic jar

Tags: shaders, glass

I'm trying to make a simple scene featuring cashews in a cashew jar. In real life, the container is clear plastic and you can see through it with no issue or distortion. In Blender, it is the exact opposite.

How do I remove the distortion from the cashews in the jar? I've tried adjusting the IOR value, tried disabling the Refraction option in the Object panel, but nothing works. I've come so far on this project and this is the last step in finishing it up for myself.

Note: I am specifically referring to the distortion/blurriness of the cashews on the center of the flat sides. Not on the parts of the jar that are curved. I just want to be able to clearly see the cashews

Screenshots:

[image: scene setup]

[image: jar shader setup]

[image: render]

[image: cashews without jar visible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'ghosting' is caused by mixing glass with transparency.

Use a simple *Glass BSDF* shader instead, and it should work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem I had been smacking my head against for days

Comment: No problem :). I encountered the same issue just last week, otherwise I wouldn't have a clue.